# How can i replace the table name in sql query?

Tags: php, sql, regex, preg-replace

I have this code

```
$Models = [
'users' => 'm_users',
'products' => 'm_products',
'customers' => 'm_customers'];

$string = "SELECT users as Name,`users`.`family` AS Family, products.id AS PID, `customers`.`id` AD CID FROM users INNER JOIN customers INNER JOIN products WHERE customers.customers = 1 and users.users = 2 and `products`.`id` = 1 and products.name = 'me' ORDER BY customers.id DESC";
$string_1 = "SELECT users FROM users";
foreach ($Models as $alias => $table) {
$string = preg_replace("/(\s|,)`?{$alias}`?/", "$1`{$table}`", $string);
}
```

And i want to replace the table name, but it's not working for any sql query string
Like **$string** and **$string_1**

Comment: What is your expected output for `$string_1`?

Comment: Working . https://3v4l.org/Rq8mb

Comment: Well, this can get a bit hard. As your SQL is not 100% proper made. If you just replace your table name, you will run into troubles with your WHERE condition in $string_1. Not to mention that $string_1 will fail due missing `s after FROM as table declaration. There is also a Field called users, just like the table name, this does not make it easier. Is it possible to change the given SQL Query? If so, a proper simple regex could be made to replace all table names, with the functionality still given.

Comment: I mean, it should work for the $string and $string_1 but it's not working for $string_1
You can try it

Comment: @natheriel no
Change is not possible.
Essentially, I want to be correct for each discipline.

Comment: @JimWright output like this => "SELECT users FROM m_users"

Comment: Well, in this case your solution will have to become more complex. As it is forced to know what part of the SQL Query will be changed. I will try to come up with something.

Comment: Why others do negative vote for my question?

Comment: @natheriel It should be the one that knows all sql commands.

Comment: well, know all SQL could get quite tricky. As this would include Sub Select and all kind of other stuff. This is not impossible, but takes a lot to do.I guess no one will create the whole code for you. We just can give you hints, on how to it. So you can understand and try to build on to this.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace only the table selecting FROM, but not table references within the SELECT i.e. `users.some_field`.

```
$str = 'SELECT users, users.some_field FROM users';
preg_replace("/(?<=FROM\s)(users)/", "m_users", $str);
// SELECT users, users.some_field FROM m_users
```

EDIT: This one should replace table references within the SELECT.

```
$str = 'SELECT users, users.some_field FROM users';
preg_replace("/(?<=FROM\s)(users)|(users(?=\.))/", "m_users", $str);
// SELECT users, m_users.some_field FROM m_users
```

To put this into your loop:

```
$Models = [
    'users' => 'm_users',
    'products' => 'm_products',
    'customers' => 'm_customers'
];
$string = "SELECT users as Name,`users`.`family` AS Family, products.id AS PID, `customers`.`id` AD CID FROM users INNER JOIN customers INNER JOIN products WHERE customers.customers = 1 and users.users = 2 and `products`.`id` = 1 and products.name = 'me' ORDER BY customers.id DESC";
foreach ($Models as $alias => $table) {
    $string = preg_replace("/(?<=FROM\s)({$alias})|({$alias}(?=\.))/", $table, $string);
}
```

Comment: There should be a comprehensive solution for all of them.This solution is just for this.

Comment: In the first example I gave you an answer to your problem, not a fully coded solution. It's not hard to put it into a loop. Luckily for you I had already started implementing it but in the future do not just expect people to write code for you. If I had read your comment before I was finished your attitude would have deterred me from updating the answer.

Comment: @shahinataei This quys solution will work for your case.

Comment: @JimWright Thank you, But which comment? I did not mean that your answer was not helpful.
I mean, I'm looking for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @shahinataei Your first comment comes across as invalidating the answer because it didn't give you a coded solution. Does the last snippet achieve what you want?